# Add data from a query into a nested table

Tags: sql, plsql

How to add data from a query into a nested table?

I have my nested table : `TYPE TABLE_DATA IS TABLE OF NUMBER;`
and my query `SELECT num FROM table_one JOIN table_two t2 ON table_one.num = t2.num WHERE f1.id = pid;`

I want to have the `num` of each row store in my nested table.
(I must use a nested table.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`BULK COLLECT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#i49139):

```
DECLARE
   TYPE table_data IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
   l_data table_data;
BEGIN
   SELECT num 
     BULK COLLECT INTO l_data 
     FROM table_one 
     JOIN table_two t2 ON table_one.num = t2.num 
    WHERE f1.id = pid;
END;
```